# Laravel Consulta con WHERE NOT IN

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Tengo la siguiente consulta SQL

```
SELECT * from autor where autor.Id_autor not in 
       (select ca.fk_autor from cntrl_autor ca 
        join autor a on a.Id_autor = ca.fk_autor 
        where ca.fk_doc=7993)
```

Como puedo convertirlo a como lo maneja el Laravel query builder?

Comment: Puedes usar DB::RAW y pasar tu consulta o puedes verificar si esto funciona DB::table('autor')
 ->whereNotIn('Id_autor',
  DB::table('cntrl_autor')
   ->join('autor', 'cntrl_autor.fk_autor', '=', 'autor.Id_autor')
   ->where('cntrl_autor.fk_doc', 7993)
   ->pluck('autor.Id_autor')->values()
  )->get();

Comment: funciono con lo que me dijiste solo que le tuve que quitar el get

Comment: OKOK voy a ponerlo como respuesta para que si alguien busca algo similar pueda encontrar la respuesta sin leer los comentarios.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar DB::RAW y pasar tu consulta o puedes emplear lo siguiente

```
DB::table('autor')
  ->whereNotIn('Id_autor', DB::table('cntrl_autor')
  ->join('autor', 'cntrl_autor.fk_autor', '=', 'autor.Id_autor')
  ->where('cntrl_autor.fk_doc', 7993)
  ->pluck('autor.Id_autor')->values());
```

Comment: amigo, y si por ejemplo lo quiero combinar con algunas clausas where por ejemplo que además de eso, el nombre del autor sea como 'Alberto' o si el id es '123', podrías decirme donde iria? Abajo del wherenot in o arriba de el. Porque he estado tratando de hacerlo pero no me respeta mi consulta como tal

Comment: $filtro = DB::table('autor') ->where('nombre', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%') ->where('apellidos', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%') ->where('pseudonimo', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%') ->where('Id_autor', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%') ->whereNotIn('Id_autor', DB::table('cntrl_autor') ->join('autor', 'cntrl_autor.fk_autor', '=', 'autor.Id_autor') ->where('cntrl_autor.fk_doc', $documento->Id_doc) ->pluck('autor.Id_autor') ->values()) ->orderBy('Id_autor', 'desc')->paginate(10);